# Beautifulsoup HTML data extraction with BeautifulSoup and Python

Tags: python, html, xml, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have HTML text that looks like many instances of the following structure:

```
<DOC>
<DOCNO> XXX-2222 </DOCNO>
<FILEID>AP-NR-02-12-88 2344EST</FILEID>
<HEAD>Reports Former Saigon Officials Released from Re-education Camp</HEAD>
<TEXT>
Lots of text here
</TEXT>
</DOC>
```

What I need to do is index each structure, with the DocNo, Headline, and Text, to later be analysed (tokenised, etc.).

I was thinking of using BeautifulSoup, and this is the code I have so far:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup (file("AP880212.html").read()) 
num = soup.findAll('docno')
```

But this only gives me results of the following format:

```
<docno> AP880212-0166 </docno>, <docno> AP880212-0167 </docno>, <docno> AP880212-0168 </docno>, <docno> AP880212-0169 </docno>, <docno> AP880212-0170 </docno>
```

How do I extract the numbers within the <> ? And link them with the headlines and texts?

Thank you very much,

Sasha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
html = """<DOC>
<DOCNO> XXX-2222 </DOCNO>
<FILEID>AP-NR-02-12-88 2344EST</FILEID>
<HEAD>Reports Former Saigon Officials Released from Re-education Camp</HEAD>
<TEXT>
Lots of text here
</TEXT>
</DOC>
"""

import bs4

d = {}

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, features="xml")
docs = soup.findAll("DOC")
for doc in docs:
    d[doc.DOCNO.getText()] = (doc.HEAD.getText(), doc.TEXT.getText())

print d
#{u' XXX-2222 ': 
#   (u'Reports Former Saigon Officials Released from Re-education Camp', 
#    u'\nLots of text here\n')}
```

Note that I pass `features="xml"` to the constructor. This is because there are a lot of non-standard html tags in your input. You will probably also want to `.strip()` text before you save it into the dictionary so it is not so whitespace sensitive (unless that is your intention, of course).

**Update:**

If there are multiple DOC's in the same file, and the `features="xml"` is limiting to one, its probably because the XML parser is expecting to have only one root element.

E.g. If you wrap your entire input XML in a single root element, it should work:

```
<XMLROOT>
    <!-- Existing XML (e.g. list of DOC elements) -->
</XMLROOT>
```

so you can either do this in your file, or what I would suggest is to do this programmatically on the input text before you pass it to beautifulsoup:

```
root_element_name = "XMLROOT"  # this can be anything
rooted_html = "<{0}>\n{1}\n</{0}>".format(root_element_name, html)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(rooted_html, features="xml")
```

Comment: And if I wanted to read it out a series of .html files out of a directory?

Currently I'm doing 

path = '/TREC-AP88-90-qrels1-50/Docs'

for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'*.html') ):

soup = BeautifulSoup (file(infile).read(), features="xml") 

and then your code, but it's not giving me the correct results..

Comment: In fact, it's the 'xml' part that makes it stop after the first doc.. is there any way to go around that?

Comment: @user2070177 see my update. Ive tested it with multiple docs and it works.

Comment: @user2070177 You could wrap this code in a function that takes the raw html text and returns a dictionary; the return dict which you can then aggregate into a master dictionary (in the scope of your main directory/file iteration loop) using `dict.update(..)`. This is a much cleaner and better separated design.

Answer (score 2):

To get the contents of the tags:

```
docnos = soup.findAll('docno')
for docno in docnos:
    print docno.contents[0]
```

Comment: and if I wanted to link the docs nos, the titles and the docs?

Comment: You can iterate over `soup.findAll('doc')`, collecting the tag contents you want before iterating over `soup.findAll('docno')` and creating keys in the first loop and establishing values in the second loop. That is to say, have a nested loop (not an additional loop).

Comment: Also consider using `BeautifulStoneSoup` since this is xml. Its easy to use (just like BeautifulSoup). Do `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup` and use it exactly as you would ordinarily

Comment: @That1Guy `BeautifulStoneSoup` is deprecated in `bs4`. I admit its what I first tried as well :). It has been replaced by passing `features="xml"` kwarg to the `BeautifulSoup` constructor.

Comment: @PreetKukreti Absolutely right. I was under the impression the OP was using BeautifulSoup 3 (`findAll` vs `find_all` in their code). Thank you for the correction. I personally use 3 as I've found bs4 to be slightly buggy.

Answer (score 0):

```
docnos = soup.findAll('docno')
for docno in docnos:
       print docno.renderContents()
```

You can also use `renderContents()`   to extract information from tags.