# Parsing many HTML documents with BeautifulSoup and Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have HTML text that looks like many instances of the following structure:

```
<DOC>
<DOCNO> XXX-2222 </DOCNO>
<FIRST>Reports Former Saigon Officials Released from Re-education Camp</FIRST>
<TEXT>
Lots of text here
</TEXT>
</DOC>
<DOC>
<DOCNO> YYYY-0001 </DOCNO>
<FIRST>AP-ONU-ISRAEL -URGENT-</FIRST>
<TEXT>
 Text
</TEXT>
</DOC>
etc, etc...
```

What I need to do is index each structure, with the DocNo, First, and Text, to later be analysed (tokenised, etc.).

I was thinking of using BeautifulSoup, but I need to extract several things together- how do I do that and link them all?

I would like a format such as :

```
[(XXX-2222, "Reports Former Saigon Officials Released from Re-education Camp", "Lots of text here"), (YYYY-0001, "AP-ONU-ISRAEL -URGENT-", "Text"), etc...)
```

Thank you!

S.

Comment: This is not HTML. Not even close! Could it perhaps be *XML*?

Comment: the file formats are in html, while the files themselves are part of a linguistic corpus..

Comment: I don't understand--whatever you posted here is *not* HTML. Are you asking us how to parse some HTML you aren't showing? Also, where is the code with what *you* tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Beautifulsoup HTML data extraction with BeautifulSoup and Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864652/beautifulsoup-html-data-extraction-with-beautifulsoup-and-python)

Comment: yup, that was my post too, except the answers that I got were not working 100%, so I decided to give more code. The format of these files is '.html', but this is the format that they are in.

Answer (score 2):

This is not html from what I can tell, so I'm not going to use Beautifulsoup. Here's an ElementTree approach:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
from collections import namedtuple

xml = """
<DOC>
<DOCNO> XXX-2222 </DOCNO>
<FIRST>Reports Former Saigon Officials Released from Re-education Camp</FIRST>
<TEXT>
Lots of text here
</TEXT>
</DOC>
<DOC>
<DOCNO> YYYY-0001 </DOCNO>
<FIRST>AP-ONU-ISRAEL -URGENT-</FIRST>
<TEXT>
 Text
</TEXT>
</DOC>
"""

Record = namedtuple('DOC', 'DOCNO FIRST TEXT')

def wrapxmlfragment(fragment):
    return '<root>{}</root>'.format(fragment)

def getrecords(xml):
    """Return list of records contained in an xml string"""
    docs = ET.fromstring(xml)
    return [recordfromDOC(doc) for doc in docs.findall('DOC')]

def recordfromDOC(DOC):
    return Record(
        DOC.find('DOCNO').text.strip(),
        DOC.find('FIRST').text.strip(),
        DOC.find('TEXT').text.strip()
    )

print records
firstrecord = records[0]
print firstrecord[0]
print firstrecord.DOCNO
```

It's easy to extend this to work from a list of files:

```
def getrecordsfromfiles(filelist):
    records = []
    for filename in filelist:
        with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
            records.extend(getrecords(wrapxmlfragment(fp.read())))
    return records

records = getrecords(wrapxmlfragment(xml))
```

However this is a very poor (and duplicate) question.

Comment: It's not duplicate because the other answers had not provided information about _several_ html documents. I am sorry that you think that way. But thank you for your answer.